# Python list comprehension syntax error

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Using a for loop, the following python code works.

```
for item in results:
    item ['currentservertime'] = int(time.time())
```

I would like to do it with a list comprehension however.  So I have tried the following, but i get a syntax error on the =

```
item['currentservertime'] = int(time.time()) for item in results
```

where am i going wrong?

Comment: ps i should mention that i am just starting python

Comment: That's not how LCs work, and that's not what LCs are for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A list comprehension won't work here, since you're not at any time building a list - you are changing values in various dictionaries. A list comprehension would be the right tool if your original code was of the form:

```
currentservertime = []
for item in results:
    currentservertime.append(int(time.time())
```

Which would translate into the list comprehension:

```
currentservertime = [int(time.time()) for item in results]
```

As it stands, your existing loop is the clearest and most direct way to implement what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
[i.update({'currentservertime': int(time.time())}) for i in results]
```